Computing expectation in Mathematica
When typing the following in Mathematica, I get the following answer,
Expectation[If[x >= a, x, 0], x \[Distributed] LaplaceDistribution[u, s]]


I am trying to do this computation myself:
f[x_] := PDF[LaplaceDistribution[u, s]][x];
F[x_] := If[x >= a, x, 0] Integrate[f[x], x] - Integrate[Integrate[f[x], x], x]
Limit[F[x], x -> +\[Infinity]] - F[a]


As you can see, the second branch of the Mathematica result has an extra +u.
I am obviously doing something stupid. What is it?
Thanks!

@mvc Your first Mathematica result is correct, but your own computation is wrong.
Let $$f_X(x)=
\begin{cases}
 \frac{e^{\frac{u-x}{s}}}{2 s} & x\geq u \\
 \frac{e^{\frac{x-u}{s}}}{2 s} & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$
for the Laplace distribution.
Then the expected value is
$$E[X\ge a]=\int_a^{\infty} x\cdot f_X(x)\, dx = 
\begin{cases}
 \frac{1}{2} (a+s) e^{\frac{u-a}{s}} & a\geq u \\
 \frac{1}{2} (s-a) e^{\frac{a-u}{s}}+u & \text{True}
\end{cases}$$
